# How to use document.getElementById() method in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written `hide()` and `show()` functions in javascript and calling them on `onmousedown` in `HTML` code.

**Functions as below:**

```
function show() {
  document.getElementById("formDiv").style.display = "block";
}

function hide() {
  document.getElementById("formDiv").style.display = "none";
}
```

I want to convert this into `Angularjs` code. Can I write like this?

```
$scope.show = function() {
  document.getElementById("formDiv").style.display = "block";
}

$scope.hide = function() {
  document.getElementById("formDiv").style.display = "none";
}
```

Can we use `document.getElementById()` in `Angularjs`? I am new to `angularjs`. Can anyone please help me out for this?

Comment: Well, you *can* use it, that does not mean that you *should* though.

Comment: you can probably achieve what you want using ng-if, if you just want to show and hide.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The beauty of Angular is that the state of your data should control what happens to your view.

In the case of the functions you are calling, it appears like you want to use maybe `ng-show`/`ng-hide`/`ng-if`.

[Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

```
<div class="elementYouWantToTarget" ng-show="expressionOrVariableThatEvaluatesToTrueOrFalseWhichWillEitherShowOrHideYourElementComingFromAnAngularControllerInThisElementsScope">
   <stuff>...</stuff>
</div>
```

And in your controller

```
angular.controller("myAwesomeExampleControllerExplainingAngular", ["$scope", controllerFn]);

function controllerFn($scope) {
 $scope.expressionOrVariableThatEvaluatesToTrueOrFalseWhichWillEitherShowOrHideYourElementComingFromAnAngularControllerInThisElementsScope = true;
}
```

#### EDIT: So according to Amit (and if I understood correctly), he wants to show or hide this element based on mouse down event. Once again if we stick to the focus that we want to change the data in angular to perform view state changes we can use `ng-mousedown` directive and attach it to your element:

```
<div class="elementYouWantToTarget" 
    ng-show="expressionOrVariableThatEvaluatesToTrueOrFalseWhichWillEitherShowOrHideYourElementComingFromAnAngularControllerInThisElementsScope"
    ng-mousedown="expressionLivingInYourControllerSomewhereThatIsCalledWhenTheMouseDownDeventFiresOnYourElement()"
    ng-mouseup="expressionDoingTheSameThingExceptForWhenTheMouseUpEventHappens()">
   <stuff>...</stuff>
</div>
```

And in your controller (PS. I'm assuming on mouse up the element disappears, otherwise you don't need the ng-mouseup directive or functions bound to it).

```
angular.controller("myAwesomeExampleControllerExplainingAngular", ["$scope", controllerFn]);

function controllerFn($scope) {
 $scope.expressionOrVariableThatEvaluatesToTrueOrFalseWhichWillEitherShowOrHideYourElementComingFromAnAngularControllerInThisElementsScope = false;
 $scope.expressionLivingInYourControllerSomewhereThatIsCalledWhenTheMouseDownDeventFiresOnYourElement = function reallyLongButShouldBeNamedStillFn($event) {
  //setting variable to true shows element based on ng-show
  $scope.expressionOrVariableThatEvaluatesToTrueOrFalseWhichWillEitherShowOrHideYourElementComingFromAnAngularControllerInThisElementsScope = true;
 }

 $scope.expressionDoingTheSameThingExceptForWhenTheMouseUpEventHappens() = nameAllYourFunctionsFn($event) {
  //setting variable to false hides element based on ng-show. 
  $scope.expressionOrVariableThatEvaluatesToTrueOrFalseWhichWillEitherShowOrHideYourElementComingFromAnAngularControllerInThisElementsScope = false;
 }
}
```

Comment: just for the nice variable name you deserves the upvote

Comment: DAMP Programming is my life. Thank you haha.

Comment: I want to display that div on mouse down.

Comment: Alright I'll update the answer. Theres a directive for that :-D.

Comment: Does this clarify @Amit

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if this answers your question, otherwise I'm happy to provide more detail etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95269/discussion-between-sean-larkin-and-amit).

Comment: As you said I have written code as --> <div id="formDiv" ng-show="isVisible" ng-mousedown="show()" ng-mouseup="hide()">-->JS-->   var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller("myController",function($scope,$event){
$scope.isVisible=false;  
$scope.show=function($event){
$scope.isVisible=true;
}
$scope.hide=function($event){
$scope.isVisible=false;
}
});  but it is not working . Any changes needed?

Answer (score 11):

Even if you shouldn't have to, there's occasions where you want to do it (for instance, comunicating with other iframe). then, it's good to use $document for unit testing purposes.
In that case:
Inject $document in your controller and use it. Remember $document returns an array.

```
$document[0].getElementById('element-id')
```

For instance, you can reload another iframe's content with

```
$document[0].getElementById('element-id').contentDocument.location.reload(true);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is it necessary to use [0] before getElementById when using $document?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `document.getElementById()` in Angularjs, but manipulating HTML in a controller is not a good practice.

I recommend you to create a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and do this kind of stuff there.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ngShow` for controlling the style, and `ngMousedown` for setting the flag:

```
<form id="formDiv" ng-show="isVisible" ng-mousedown="isVisible=false" ng-mouseup="isVisible=true"></form>
```

And In your controller, just set `$scope.isVisible = true;` (or `false`) to toggle between the states. You also have the `ngHide` for controlling whether to hide the element based on the expression.

What both `ngShow` and `ngHide` does is toggling the `ng-hide` class that set the `display:none;` to the element.